# jQuery broken function after added new function

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

What's wrong here? The alert function was working until I added this new function to it.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? It just simply doesn't fire the alert anymore.

```
<input value="1"  type="checkbox" name="salgsvilkar" id="checkbox2"  style="float:left;"
        />

    {literal}
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       //checkbox
       $("#scrollwrap").click(function(){
        $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight');
        });​
    });

    $(function(){
       //button
       $("#fullfor_btn").click(function(e){
           if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false)
           {
               alert("Please accept the terms of sale."); 
               e.preventDefault();
           }
       });
     });
    </script>
      {/literal}


<button type="submit" class="submit" name="{$method}" id="fullfor_btn" title="Fullfør bestillingen nå" value="">&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false) {
```

why not just use the much more readable:

```
if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked')) {
```

EDIT: If your intention is for the alert to fire when the checkbox is *not* checked:

```
if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: Because the alert has to appear if the box is not checked.

Comment: @Kyle - in that case, the problem is with that statement :). Just get rid of `== false`

Comment: Thanks :) So if it has `!` it means `not`?

Comment: yes exactly, i had corrected this in the example i posted. `!` is a negation

Comment: @Kyle - yes, ! means not, so `!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked')` means *not* checked, thus `!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false` is an awfully long and confusing way to say *is* checked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get onto reading that, just had to fix these things quick :)

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is probably not what you intended, as karim79 said.

```
if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false)
```

is identical in function to

```
if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == true)
```

so your alert will only trigger when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your code in the same $(function(){ code }) in your example, you are setting the document ready twice

```
 $(function() {
   //checkbox
   $("#scrollwrap").click(function(){
    $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight');
   });​

   //button
   $("#fullfor_btn").click(function(e){
       if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))
       {
           alert("Please accept the terms of sale."); 
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the double doc ready to see if it'd force the alert, But even after removing it, the alert still doesn't fire.

Comment: you code works just fine, i think you have a conflict somewhere else in your code. All i can see is `if(!$("#checkbox2").is(':checked') == false)` could be just: `if($("#checkbox2").is(':checked'))`

Comment: That's a moot point, since jQuery event handlers do not overwrite each other.  Both handlers would be attached.  Try it.

Comment: @nick: i know it works it was just an optimization the main problem was the if with the double negation. Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

Though it seems a little odd that you'd trigger the alert when the checkbox is checked, instead of when it is not.